# Pay payments in paypal without direct Login

Tags: paypal, cron

i am new to paypal , my client need to pay the payment in the date which was set by 
the admin , is it possible to do this using cron . is any method is there in paypal . i 
search in google but i didn't find the answer . using key with user name password can we able 
to do it in cron job itself . or else in the recurring payment method able to update the payment dates . help me to do it

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Adaptive Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/), specifically [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) and [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).

You can Preapproval to generate a preapproval key.  The payer signs in to authenticate and create this preapproval profile.

Once the profile has been created you can use the Pay API with the preapproval key included to submit future payments on that person's behalf without the need for any further authentication.  This allows you to fully automate payments on whatever date for whatever amount you need.